# D8 - how to group view by paragraph term reference parent

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms, paragraphs

I can't group view results by a taxonomy term's parent...

I have a content type of plant, with "field_plant_locations", referencing the paragraph type, "plant_locations". In this paragraph, I have a term reference field (field_location) to a "locations" taxonomy.

I've created a plant view. In it, I have a contextual filter to the Plant node ID. I've added all sorts of relationships trying to get to the taxonomy parent. Currently: field_location
field_plant_locations: Paragraph
(field_plant_locations: Paragraph) field_location: Taxonomy term
(field_location: Taxonomy term) Parent
(Parent) Parent

I've rearranged, I've tried to change relationships, I've tried getting the parent. I can't seem to find where to get that parent term. The closest 'parent' I can find is the field parent. I don't see anything letting me get Taxonomy parent.

**So I get the plant field as a parent:**

*Field_plant_locations:  
Spain, England, Germany, Alabama*

**I want to be able to group by location parents/grandparents to get a result like this:**

*Europe:   Spain, England, Germany

North America:   U.S.: Alabama*

Comment: It is a bit unclear which data is stored in which layer, but isn't the taxonomy term the actual country you are looking for? Since you've added a relationship to the taxonomy term, can't you select the taxonomy title as a field, optionally hide it from display using the checkbox and finally group the rows in the by the value of the field using the formatting settings?

Comment: Yeah - the taxonomy hierarchy is contenent -> country -> state.  I was assuming I could do exactly what you suggest... but the only parent available is a field parent for the content type - not the taxonomy. I don't know if there's a reordering of references or fields that needs to happen - I've sorted them all over the place trying to find what works, but found nothing.